I want to extract table and its associated columns from a query in Python
The expected output should be based on outer main query and subquery like below:
Table: A_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING

Columns from main query: 

    MI_KEY_ACC_SWITCHING, CURRENCY, DEPARTMENT, EFF_STA_DTE

Columns from subqueries: 

    CURR_BUSS_DATE, SUITE_ID

--------------------------------

Table: U_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING

Columns from main query: 

    MI_KEY_ACC_SWITCHING, CURRENCY, DEPARTMENT, EFF_STA_DTE

Columns from subqueries: 

--------------------------------

Table: A_MPAY_BUKDB.MI_DATE_CONTROL

Columns from main query: 

Columns from subqueries: 

    CURR_BUSS_DATE, SUITE_ID

Please help me someone totally hovering around this since 2 days.
import sqlparse
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

def extract_columns_and_tables(sql_query):
    # Parse the SQL query and split it into individual statements
    parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql_query)

    # Initialize the dictionary to hold table and column mappings
    table_columns_map = defaultdict(list)

    # Regex patterns for INSERT INTO, SELECT, UPDATE, SET, and subqueries
    insert_into_pattern = re.compile(r"INSERT\s+INTO\s+([\w.]+)\s*\((.*?)\)", re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    select_pattern = re.compile(r"SELECT\s+(.*?)\s+FROM", re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    from_pattern = re.compile(r"FROM\s+([\w.]+)\s*(\w*)", re.IGNORECASE)
    update_pattern = re.compile(r"UPDATE\s+([\w.]+)\s+SET\s+(.*?)\s*(FROM\s+[\w.]+)?", re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    subquery_pattern = re.compile(r"\((SELECT.*?)\)", re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)

    def parse_subqueries(query_str):
        """
        Recursively parse subqueries within the SQL query.
        """
        subqueries = subquery_pattern.findall(query_str)
        for subquery in subqueries:
            # Recursively parse each subquery
            parse_query(subquery)

    def parse_query(query_str):
        """
        Parse a single query for table and column mappings.
        """
        # Handle INSERT INTO statements
        insert_match = insert_into_pattern.search(query_str)
        if insert_match:
            insert_table = insert_match.group(1).strip()
            insert_columns = [col.strip() for col in insert_match.group(2).split(",")]
            for col in insert_columns:
                table_columns_map[insert_table].append(col)

        # Handle SELECT-FROM statements
        select_match = select_pattern.findall(query_str)
        from_match = from_pattern.search(query_str)
        if select_match and from_match:
            select_columns = [col.strip() for col in select_match[0].split(",")]
            from_table = from_match.group(1).strip()
            for col in select_columns:
                table_columns_map[from_table].append(col)

        # Handle UPDATE statements
        update_match = update_pattern.search(query_str)
        if update_match:
            update_table = update_match.group(1).strip()
            set_columns = [col.strip() for col in update_match.group(2).split(",")]
            # Map the SET columns to the UPDATE table
            for col in set_columns:
                table_columns_map[update_table].append(col)

            # If there's a FROM clause in the UPDATE statement, handle subqueries
            if update_match.group(3):
                from_table = update_match.group(3).strip()
                table_columns_map[from_table].append('subquery')  # Indicate it's from a subquery
                parse_subqueries(query_str)  # Parse subqueries within the FROM clause

        # Recursively parse for subqueries within the query
        parse_subqueries(query_str)

    # Loop through each SQL statement and extract columns and tables
    for statement in parsed:
        query_str = str(statement)
        parse_query(query_str)

    # Generate individual DataFrames for each table
    dataframes = {}
    for table, columns in table_columns_map.items():
        df = pd.DataFrame({"Table_Name": [table] * len(columns), "Columns": columns})
        dataframes[table] = df

    return dataframes

# Example SQL Query with INSERT, SELECT, and UPDATE
sql_query = """
INSERT INTO A_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING
(MI_KEY_ACC_SWITCHING, CURRENCY, DEPARTMENT)
SELECT MI_KEY_ACC_SWITCHING, CURRENCY, DEPARTMENT
FROM U_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING
WHERE EFF_STA_DTE = (
    SELECT CURR_BUSS_DATE
    FROM A_MPAY_BUKDB.MI_DATE_CONTROL
    WHERE SUITE_ID = 'MPY'
);

UPDATE A_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING
SET CURRENCY = 'USD', DEPARTMENT = 'HR'
FROM U_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING
WHERE EFF_STA_DTE = '2023-01-01';
"""

# Extract tables and columns
dataframes = extract_columns_and_tables(sql_query)

# Print the DataFrames for each table
for table, df in dataframes.items():
    print(f"Table: {table}")
    print(df)


Thanks @marc_s for the edit. can someone help me on my query?
